# Error: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'plot'

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, attributeerror

I am using python 3.6 and while running the below code i am getting as error which says
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Sagar/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/graphfile.py", line 10, in 
    plt.plot(x,y)
AttributeError: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'plot'

The code is

```
import matplotlib as plt
x=[]
y=[]
readfile=open("graph.txt","r")
data=readfile.read().split("\n")
for i in data:
     val=i.split(",")
     x.append(int(val[0]))
     y.append(int(val[1]))
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The import statement should be like:

```
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Comment: why do we  haveimport pyplot?

Comment: Because the pyplot module of matplotlib contains the necesary tools and functions for plotting.

Source: https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html

Answer (score 0):

`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`

This should work. You need to import plot as well. Just importing matplotlib is not enough.